# Transpose row values into columns

Tags: sql, toad

I have a sample query that returns:

[image: First screenshot]

The query is:

```
SELECT departmentID, departmentMembers, workingHours
FROM timeTracker
WHERE departmentID = 11111
```

---

Basically, I want to transpose the values of `departmentMembers` column and make them into new columns and the values for each column of `workingHours` will be the values those columns. See the second screenshot for what I want.
Notice that `departmentMembers` column is not there anymore in the following screenshot:

[image: Second Screenshot]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select departmentID, 
       sum(case when departmentMembers = 'ADMIN_FEE' then workingHours else 0 end) as admin_fee,
       . . .
from timeTracker
where departmentID = 11111
group by departmentID;
```

The `. . .` is for the remaining columns.

Answer (score 0):

use pivot table to transpose column

```
select departmentID, [ADMIN_FEE],[AGT_COMM],[AGT_OVER],[IRPM],[NCB_A],[VIP_FEE] from (SELECT departmentID, departmentMembers, workingHours FROM timeTracker WHERE departmentID = 11111) as SourceTable Pivot (max(workingHours) for departmentMembers IN ([ADMIN_FEE],[AGT_COMM],[AGT_OVER],[IRPM],[NCB_A],[VIP_FEE]) AS PivotTable;
```